# Query by an associated model's subclass in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, sti

I have used Single Table Inheritance (STI) to create some Models with subclassed from a common parent. A separate model has an association with the superclass. Eg: as follows...

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :smoothies
end

class Apple < Fruit
end

class Banana < Fruit
end

class Smoothie < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fruit
end
```

Is there any way to query for a certain subclass without manually creating a method for each subclass?

I would like to be able to do something along the lines of `my_smoothie.apple` to get an `Apple` instance if `my_smoothie` is associated with an `Apple`

**Update**

My use case is actually where I have a relation of Smoothies and I want to do `some_smoothies.apples` to get a relation containing any associated Apples.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a my_smoothie.fruit, you should get back an Apple object (not a Fruit object, Rails magic).  You may be good as is.

Comment: Thanks @Swards - This doesn't entirely solve my problem. I have updated the question to better reflect what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

could you do this?

```
my_smoothie.fruit.where(type: "Apple")
```

Of course if you need to dynamically infer the name of your subclasses you could use

```
subclass_object.class.to_s # if you have an instantiated object e.g. of 'apple'
subclass.to_s # if you start form the subclass e.g. of Apple
```

And if this is ok for you, consider creating [named scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) for it

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations?view=asciicast